# Phone Gap windows Phone 7 vs Phone Gap windows Phone 8

Tags: cordova

What is the difference between PhoneGap Winodows-Phone7 and PhoneGap windows-Phone8 platforms. If i use any (WindowsPhone7 / WindowsPhone8) will it support other fully, if no what is best to use and why? and how to achieve compatibility of both using only one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you have to use only one project ?

You just have to create one Phonegap project for each Platform and then, copy/paste your HTML/CSS/Javascript code in the "assets" directory.

Maybe you can automate this copy/paste operation with a simple script or better, by using branches and merge featues of a revision control system like Git or SVN.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create app for both WP8 and WP7, you better go for WP7 app. It will be supported for both WP8 and WP7. In WP8, You will have new features as mentioned in the link http://mobile.dzone.com/articles/windows-phone-8-sdk-new. Also, you will not have zooming of the pages.